# Mutate a new column that is the list of the row_id of minimally different rows from .row

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

```
tibble(
  A= c("x","x","y","y"),
  B= c("y","y","y","y"),
  C= c("x","y","z","y")
  )  %>%
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    .before = "A"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    neighs_id = list(
      c("2"),
      c("1,4"),
      c("4"),
      c("2,3")
  )
  ) %>% View()
```

The output of `neighs_id` is the list of `id_row` when is `TRUE` the condition that exactly `==1` value of `A`,`B`, or `C` is `!=` from the values in that `.row`, in the same columns.

I want a code to replace the second mutate with `map` that has as outcome a `list` (keep: the operation would be `rowise`!) of all the rows that, given a selection of columns, have `1` column with a value `!=` column[.row].

In theory, I could setup a square matrix of `id` X `id`, check the `sum` of columns of the tibble such that `column[id] =! column[column[.id]` and then keep all the matches where the element `== 1`, but I think that should be a more straightforward way to select vectorise a `filter` on these "minimally different rows", given a selector of columns.

Comment: Can you explain e.g. the output of one line? it's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: The output of `neighs_id` is the list of `id_row` when is `TRUE` the condition that exactly `1` value of `A`,`B`, or `C` is `!=` from the values in that `.row`, in the same columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R:

```r
cols = LETTERS[1:3]
tib$neighs_id <- lapply(seq(nrow(tib)), 
                        function(i) which(sapply(seq(nrow(tib)),
                                                 function(x) sum(tib[x, cols] != tib[i, cols])) == 1))
```

```r
#> pull(tib, neighs_id)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: I am trying this one. I think it will going to work. But instead of `-1`, there should be a selector.

Comment: Yes indeed, I edited with  a selector

Comment: One issue that I am encountering is that on a `tibble` with 2280 `rows`, this seems slow. It it still working after 1hr. Of course it needs to perform 2280^2 operations, but probably I would need to translate it in `map`. In future I could need to make it scale up to 1M^2.

Comment: UPDATE: it lasted 1:30 hrs. Not bad after all! I will keep this open for a day or two to see if someone can significantly improve the efficency. But I will acknowledge your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed this up is not to work with tibbles but with a matrix instead. I guess this is because tibbles (or data frames) are lists of columns so repeated extraction of rows is expensive compared to working with a matrix.

Another significant improvement can be achieved by changing the character matrix to a numeric one so that some operations can be vectorized. This way the inner `sapply` from Maël's answer can be replaced with subtraction and summing over matrix columns.

```r
n.rep <- 1
tib <- tibble(
  A=rep(c("x", "x", "y", "y"), n.rep),
  B=rep(c("y", "y", "y", "y"), n.rep),
  C=rep(c("x", "y", "z", "y"), n.rep)
)

cols <- LETTERS[1:3]
# change tibble to a matrix
tib.m <- as.matrix(tib[, cols])
# named vector used to translate values to their order
val.ord <- unique(c(tib.m))
val.ord <- setNames(seq_along(val.ord), val.ord)
# create numeric representation using the orders
tib.m[] <- val.ord[tib.m]
mode(tib.m) <- 'numeric'

tib$neighs_id <- apply(tib.m, 1, function(row) 
  which(colSums(t(tib.m) - row != 0) == 1))
```

This finishes in about a second when `n.rep` is 1000 (i.e., `tib` is a 4000-row matrix). Scaling it up to 1M, however, might still be problematic, I'm afraid. For this, using `Rcpp` might help.